# Retrieve Response HTTP Status Code from ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I throw an unhandled exception in my controller, the filterContext-->HTTPContext-->Response always returns 200-OK.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("some error");
        return View();
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the actual status from the filterContext in ActionFilterAttribute, or can I?

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filterContext.Response?.StatusCode.ToString() ?? "<null>"
```

should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to check the [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext.exception(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext.Exception) field. If all you need to know is if there was an unhandled exception going up the stack...